# Jquery Design Problem

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jquery

I'm working with Jquery and Joomla3 and Nooku framework and I need to add CSS style to my page which I'm using the following for:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addCustomTag("<script type='text/javascript' src='".JURI::root(1)."/components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>");   
JFactory::getDocument()->addCustomTag("<style src='components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css'/>");
```

The first `JFactory` line is to import a JS file into my page and it works fine.

The second line is to import the CSS file into my page, but it doesn't work, as if the **jquery.dataTables.css** had no effect.

Please help and thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Nooku Framework to build your component you can make use of the build in template engine and special `ktml` tags which makes it very easy to add assets to your page head.

First of all, you need to ensure that your component assets are in the Joomla /media folder. Example : /media/com_foo/css/bar.css

Now you can use `<ktml:style src="media://com_foor/css/bar.css"` /> in your component template.

> Please note that this only works in a template and if you are using
>   Nooku Framework 2.x.

The `<ktml:style src="[]" />` is a special tag that the template engine will replace into a correct script tag and move into the head of your page.

The `media://` is a special asset URL scheme. It's a shortcut for the Joomla media folder used in URLs to media assets. It will be filtered by the template engine upon render and replaced by the absolute path for the folder being JURI::root(). Unless you define this otherwise.

The use of the `<ktml:style src="[]" />` makes it very easy to include css files in your Nooku powered extensions and it makes your template more re-usable and simpler.

For an example check our [Nooku example todo component](https://github.com/nooku/joomla-todo/blob/master/administrator/components/com_todo/views/task/tmpl/default.html.php).

> More about the Joomla media folder can be found in the [Joomla developer best practives](https://docs.joomla.org/Development_Best_Practices#Where_should_I_place_JavaScript.2C_CSS.2C_and_Image_files_that_belong_to_my_Component.3F).
>
> For loading javascript you can use the `<ktml:script scr="[..]" />` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to use `addCustomTag` to import your scripts. You can use `addScript` and `addStylesheet` for this, or even `JHtml`. Secondly, you haven't defined the root of the path for the stylesheet.

Try replacing all you code with this:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JUri::root() . 'components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
$doc->addStylesheet(JUri::root() . 'components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css');
```

or this:

```
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css');
```

Comment: thanks for help but it didnt work , when i changed addCustomTag , even the JS functions didnt work anymore

Comment: I didn't only change `addCustomTag`. Please make sure you copied all my code exactly and **replaced** your code with it. Also make sure that the files exist in those paths by typing the following URL in your browser `www.YOURSITE.com/components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css`

Comment: i did changes but yet it didnt work , and after searching i guess the problem is with the CSS i want to include which is ThemeRoller , maybe Mootools is having conflict with JQuery on Joomla :/

Comment: Joomla ensures there are no conflicts with Mootools and jQuery. It might be something to do with your script. Please check your browser console for any errors that may be occurring

Comment: they exist within the correct paths , ok i will check thanks

Comment: If they exist and you're sure they're being imported, then it will most likely be a JS error causing the problem ;)

Comment: i'm not sure CSS is being imported

Comment: Copy this in your browser (change `YOURSITE.com` to whatever your domain is)........`www.YOURSITE.com/components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/css/jquery.d‌​ataTables.css`....If you see all your CSS code, then the file exists. If not, then you need to define your paths correctly

Comment: Aaah yes i did that and so the file exists sorry

Comment: Did you do the same for your JS file?? `www.YOURSITE.com/components/com_sgrmre/lib/DataTables-1.10.6/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`

Comment: Yes the same thing i'm having just an error after checking the console as u suggested , which is 
GET http://localhost/SystemeGestionReclamationsMRE/index.php/component/sgrmre/images/picture.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)

but that image pic i have it on another page :/ i dont understand

Comment: Ok, and where are you adding the code I provided? Which file?

Comment: on my file default.html.php which has html and php code for a list

Comment: Ok, now open your browser console, look in the source HTML code and see if you can see your 2 files inside the `<head>` tag

Comment: indeed i have them within Head

Comment: Have you tried using <link rel="stylesheet" href="linktoyourcssfile.css"> instead of <style src=...>? (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html)